# How to slice a block of HTML codes into component and import it back in?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm struggling trying to slice out a block of repetitive HTML codes into it owned file(component) and import it back in.

It's a v-for of v-row.

I need to call that **8 times**. I rather import it 8 times instead of having 8 similar-looking HTML codes polluting the main `.vue` file. The only difference is one variable `"rules"`. It's an array of rules.

> Note :
> while `rules` is only one should be dynamic & pass in
> v-for="(rule, index) in rules" while the rest of the HTML codes are identical.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <v-row v-for="(rule, index) in rules" :key="`rule-${index}`">
            <!-- ------------
        /// ⭐️ Attributes
        ----------------- -->
            <v-col md="4">
                <v-select dense outlined item-text="name" item-value="id" label="Attribute" :items="attributes" v-model="rule.attribute_id" @change="changeAttribute(index, rule.attribute_id)"></v-select>
            </v-col>

            <!-- ------------
        /// ⭐️ Operators
        ------------ -->
            <v-col md="3">
                <v-select outlined dense item-text="name" item-value="id" label="Operator" v-model="rule.operator_id" :items="rule.operators" @change="changeOperator(index, rule.attribute_id, rule.operator_id)"></v-select>
            </v-col>

            <!-- --------
        /// ⭐️ Values
        ------------- -->
            <v-col md="4">
                <v-row v-if="locationIds.includes(rule.attribute_id)">
                    <!-- -------------------------
                | City & Postal Code 
                ------------------------- -->

                    <v-col md="4" v-if="rule.attribute_id == 34">
                        <v-combobox :items="radiuses" v-model="rule.value_param" label="Radius" dense outlined></v-combobox>
                    </v-col>

                    <v-col md="8" v-if="[36].includes(rule.attribute_id) && rule.operator_id != 15">
                        <v-combobox v-model="rule.value" :items="rule.value" item-text="value_alias" item-value="value" return-object hide-selected :label="`Value (${locations.length})`" dense outlined append-outer-icon="delete" @click:append-outer="removeRuleDetail(index)"></v-combobox>
                    </v-col>

                    <!-- ----------------------
                | State/Province & Country 
                ------------------------- -->

                    <v-col md="8" v-if="[34, 35, 37].includes(rule.attribute_id) && rule.operator_id != 15">
                        <v-combobox :items="locations" item-text="value_alias" item-value="value" return-object v-model="rule.value" :label="`Value (${locations.length})`" dense outlined append-outer-icon="delete" @click:append-outer="removeRuleDetail(index)" @change="getLocations(rule.value, rule.attribute_id)"></v-combobox>
                    </v-col>

                    <v-col md="8" v-if="[35, 37].includes(rule.attribute_id) && rule.operator_id == 15">
                        <v-combobox :items="locations" item-text="value_alias" item-value="value" return-object v-model="search" :label="`Search`" dense outlined append-outer-icon="delete" @click:append-outer="removeRuleDetail(index)" @change="getLocationsBasedOnValue(search, rule.attribute_id)" append-icon="add" @click:append="selectLocation(index, rule.value)"></v-combobox>
                    </v-col>

                    <v-col md="12" v-if="[35, 37].includes(rule.attribute_id) && rule.operator_id == 15">
                        <v-combobox :items="inListLocations" item-text="value_alias" item-value="value" v-model="rule.value" :label="`Added (${inListLocations.length})`" multiple chips clear-icon="mdi-close-circle" deletable-chips></v-combobox>
                    </v-col>

                    <!-- ------------------
                | Postal Code (In List)
                -------------------- -->

                    <v-col md="8" v-if="[36].includes(rule.attribute_id) && rule.operator_id == 15">
                        <v-text-field v-model="search" :label="`Postal Code`" dense outlined append-outer-icon="delete" @click:append-outer="removeRuleDetail(index)" append-icon="add" @click:append="selectLocation(index, rule.value)"></v-text-field>
                    </v-col>

                    <v-col md="12" v-if="[36].includes(rule.attribute_id) && rule.operator_id == 15">
                        <v-combobox :items="inListLocations" item-text="value_alias" item-value="value" v-model="rule.value" :label="`Added (${inListLocations.length})`" multiple chips clear-icon="mdi-close-circle" deletable-chips></v-combobox>
                    </v-col>
                </v-row>

                <v-row>
                    <v-col md="4" v-if="weatherIds.includes(rule.attribute_id)">
                        <v-combobox :items="days" v-model="rule.value_param" label="Day" dense outlined></v-combobox>
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col md="8">
                        <v-menu v-if="rule.inputType == 'Date Range' && !locationIds.includes(rule.attribute_id)" :close-on-content-click="false" :nudge-right="40" transition="scale-transition" offset-y min-width="auto">
                            <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                                <v-text-field dense outlined v-model="rule.value" label="Values" append-icon="mdi-calendar" readonly v-bind="attrs" v-on="on"></v-text-field>
                            </template>
                            <v-date-picker range v-model="rule.value"></v-date-picker>
                        </v-menu>

                        <v-menu v-if="rule.inputType == 'Date Picker' && !locationIds.includes(rule.attribute_id)" :close-on-content-click="false" :nudge-right="40" transition="scale-transition" offset-y min-width="auto">
                            <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                                <v-text-field dense outlined v-model="rule.value" label="Values" append-icon="mdi-calendar" readonly v-bind="attrs" v-on="on"></v-text-field>
                            </template>
                            <v-date-picker v-model="rule.value"></v-date-picker>
                        </v-menu>

                        <v-select v-if="rule.inputType == 'Single Select' && !locationIds.includes(rule.attribute_id)" outlined dense item-text="value_alias" item-value="value" return-object v-model="rule.value" label="Values" :items="rule.values" @click:append-outer="removeRuleDetail(index)" append-outer-icon="delete"></v-select>

                        <v-combobox v-if="rule.inputType == 'Multi Select' && !locationIds.includes(rule.attribute_id)" multiple outlined dense item-text="value_alias" item-value="value" return-object v-model="rule.value" label="Values" :items="rule.values" @click:append-outer="removeRuleDetail(index)" append-outer-icon="delete"></v-combobox>

                        <v-text-field v-if="rule.inputType == 'Text' && !locationIds.includes(rule.attribute_id)" dense outlined required clearable v-model="rule.value" :rules="form.rules.value" label="Values" clear-icon="mdi-close-circle" append-outer-icon="delete" @click:append-outer="removeRuleDetail(index)"></v-text-field>

                        <v-text-field v-if="rule.inputType == 'Init' && !locationIds.includes(rule.attribute_id)" readonly dense outlined required clearable v-model="rule.value" :rules="form.rules.value" label="Values" clear-icon="mdi-close-circle" append-outer-icon="delete" @click:append-outer="removeRuleDetail(index)"></v-text-field>
                    </v-col>
                </v-row>
            </v-col>
        </v-row>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'Conditions',
    props: {
        rules: Array
    },
    methods: {
        onClick() {
            console.log('%c ---', 'background: linear-gradient(45deg, red, yellow, blue, green, purple)')
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

## Import

```
import Conditions from '../../../components/rules/conditions'


<Conditions :rules="selectedRuleConditions" />
```

It doesn't seem to work.

I kept getting

[image]

How would one do that ?

Comment: There is no data member called `locationIds` in the `Conditions` component. Please add one to the `data` section.

Comment: So the variables need to exist in the component file `data` section?  Can they stay in the main file `data` section?

Comment: Component templates can refer only to its own component `data`, `computed`, `props`, `methods` sections. IF you want to reference external data (e.g. `this.$root`) - you will have to introduce computed values and then refer to those in the template.

Comment: Can you please show a link or answer with a basic example base on your comment about ?  

Comment: @code-8 I understood your requirement . It's all about design the component. I will surely help you by tomorrow on this.

Comment: @code-8 I added an answer. Hope that will help you. If it helps please do accept the answer. So that it will be helpful for others as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `:rules` will only contains dynamic data then you can achieve like this way **:**

```js
Vue.component('Conditions', {
  props: ['rules'],
  template: `<ul><li v-for="rule in rules" :key="rule.id">{{ rule.name }}</li></ul>`
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    rule1Obj: [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'Alpha'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Beta'    
    }, {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Gamma'   
    }],
    rule2Obj: [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'X'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Y'    
    }],
    rule3Obj: [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'Name 1'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Name 2'    
    }, {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Name 3'   
    }]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <Conditions :rules="rule1Obj">
  </Conditions>
  
  <Conditions :rules="rule2Obj">
  </Conditions>
  
  <Conditions :rules="rule3Obj">
  </Conditions>
</div>
```

In above demo, I am just passing `:rules` dynamically based on the requirement or data you want to pass.